# RadClientExportManager - UI alignment issues for checkboxes

Tags: user-interface, ascx

I'm using RadClientExportManager to export a modal window (dynamically created by loading `UserControls` at runtime).

I have `RadCheckBoxList` in some of the ascx's that are loaded. When such a modal window is exported to PDF, the checkboxes and its text are misaligned.

This is the screenshot of how it looks on the modal window itself:
[image: This is the screenshot of how it looks on the modal window itself]

This is the screenshot of how it looks when it's exported to a PDF via RadCientExportManager:

[image: This is the screenshot of how it looks when it's exported to a PDF via RadCientExportManager]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this issue can be fixed by CSS for pseudo-elements.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .kendo-pdf-hide-pseudo-elements:after,
    .kendo-pdf-hide-pseudo-elements:before {
        display: none !important;
    }
    </style>
```